# How to Watch All Directories(Includes All Subdirectories) using Auditd?

Tags: linux, centos-7, auditd

Im using a rule in auditd which is:
 `-w /etc -p wa -k watch_etc`
But upon checking the report using `ausearch -k watch_etc -ts today | aureport -f -i`
I can't seem to find the changes I've made in the directory `/etc/auditd/rules.d/`.
However, creating a file under `/etc/` will create an entry on the report that I've used `touch` command.

> 01/24/2019 09:11:03 test open yes /usr/bin/touch root 7441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a thread that uses a different method but with the same results.
I've come up with a solution:

```
-a exit,always  -F dir=/etc  -p wa -F key=watch_etc
```

Comment: Hi Gilroy. Please consider explaining what each option does in the above line, or referencing a thread that explains this.
Thank you.

Comment: @TelamonAegisthus see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-defining_audit_rules_and_controls